# React.JS. How can I apply material theme on child component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

This is my JSX:

```jsx
<FormControl>
    <ButtonGroup className="groupedHorizontal">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="category">Category:</InputLabel>
        <Select onChange={(event) => that.handleCategoryChange(event)}  native={true}  id="category">
            <option></option>
            {catOptions}
        </Select>
        
        <BrandsPopup />
        
        <Button onClick={(e) => that.removeCategory(e)}>Del</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
</FormControl>
```

The BrandsPopup is a component which render a material-ui Button within `<React.Fragment>`. The select and the "Del" button are fine bordered as `ButtonGroup` elements. The problem is, BrandsPopup is not bordered and does not appear as part of the group. How to apply `ButtonGroup` styles on the button, rendered from the child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ButtonGroup` uses `cloneElement` and thereby [assigns its own props](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.2/packages/material-ui/src/ButtonGroup/ButtonGroup.js) to its children. You should be able to log them to the console inside `BrandsPopup` and then just need to assign them to your button component. It is, of course, possible that this conflicts with how you are using `BrandsPopup` elsewhere in your app.

And if `BrandsPopup` indeed only contains one `Button` component you don't need the `Fragment` wrapper.

```js
<ButtonGroup className="groupedHorizontal">
  <BrandsPopup />
</ButtonGroup>


const BrandsPopup = (props) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Button
      // these come from ButtonGroup 
      className={props.className}
      color={props.color}
      variant={props.variant}
    >
      click me
    </Button>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```